# Rotation of an element around a pivot using movements and rotations

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to build a tool that will allow me to rotate objects around a pivot.

I have in my hands 2 tools:

> ```
> moveElement(element,x,y) //this allows me to move my element in x,y steps
> setRotationAngle(element,angle) //this allows me to rotate my element around it's center in angle steps.
> ```

I want to rotate my element around a custom center within my canvas, instead of it's own center.

Is this possible to emulate mathematically by just rotating the element around it's center and moving it in x,y steps at the same time?

This is what I used(from @avims) answer below:

> ```
> setRotationAngle(element, angle, x, y):
>
> setRotationAngle(element, angle)
> step_x = cos(angle) * (element.x - x) - sin(angle) * (element.y - y)
> step_y = sin(angle) * (element.x - x) + cos(angle) * (element.y - y)
> moveElement(element, step_x, step_y)
> ```

I've built this in dead simple code([click here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/jVPRasIwFP2VS19sV2d1Yy+KT+5VGOxxHSO2VxuMSWlua4P470vaZk6G2woJ3Jtzzzk5pKdAsgMG8+B1j5QVwTjIVO7qlBpWAQo8oCRYgsQjvDAqJiteZQLDh+l0PLML7BYtIEly3HKJOTDpp1IJ9huKyZYLsVJCVZZstBEs248WPaLfnRyTO4H2fOYIueTEmeibF0zrzp+mDlHyRhGUiluH7QVhHOLxB8J4tW0tM+JKgpJrVWt8VkcZYmNNRnBKZUrecqWIEYadge6OLM+ha7rpjQFNWFqxwWFKbnVFHC98nSRUIGRM1KKb067pbLrhD3ebtYs1U3oQgjsIvYNSae6GJi3cQxvZrQNrLn8DG4sz0SWQTsl4pT+GB6X4X7a8Uq/VB0QKsOWauNyBB4LLoEJdC9LXz+KbbrwcMnFRU8E1HFSD+usRWuIWmKX20dv0St6iuEVpLGV/99uM5orRlp7xbP+FTYVs370eHczf3s+f)) using the answer below (just click anywhere on the right canvas to start the calculations).

For some reason I get really off values and I think I am missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ be the center of your element $E$, let $(x_0,y_0)$ be the pivot point and let $\alpha$ be the angle of rotation.

1. Rotate $E$ by $\alpha$.
2. Calculate $v:=(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)$.
3. Rotate $v$ by $\alpha$.
4. Move $E$ to $(x_0,y_0)+v$.

For an example, see the link in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't move an element to a position, I can only move it in steps to x,y directions

Comment: Moving $E$ from $(x,y)$ to $(x_0,y_0)$ is equivalent to moving it by steps $(x_0-x,y_0-y)$, isn't it? Or maybe I misunderstood you...

Comment: the thing is I don't want to move an element to another position before starting the rotation. The pivot rotation should start from it's initial position

Comment: Ok I see. Can you rotate a single vector?
You can contact me via email and we could talk about it via skype. Could be the easiest way.

Comment: your skypename?

Comment: http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/TVHLboMwEPyVlS8hCiVA1UtQTu01UtQeSw8GlsbCWSPYEFVR/r1+QFpLtrTrmdkZ+yZInlHsxEeHXJ9ELGrTuLrkSQ6AGs9IDHsgvMJR8il5x5olfWuM8jSNM7shT+PndF3AdttgqwgbkLRQSwK75iJpldavRpvBKq4qLetuVQREON1ML27v89QpKlKspA7dP1CvJvOwZRRxlL1YJ5nzsQi2F6pZGQJDB3MZ8c1cKcLJ+ljDraSSF1eDYckY+RE+hmwa8E3Hrn5gZOztsNlDeJrJNhaB3ozKY5+CscKDkpBkMxOL/yMfjP0cZQOTBdztB1QDyq53mUax+/y6/wI=

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that works.

> ```
>     var element = new Path.Rectangle(100,100,200,100); //defined an element
>     element.fillColor = 'black';
>
>     var angle = 1; //incremental angle
>     var x = 300; //pivot point x
>     var y = 300; //pivot point y
>     var dx = element.position.x-x;
>     var dy = element.position.y-y;
>     var sin1 = Math.sin(Math.PI*angle/180);
>     var cos1 = Math.cos(Math.PI*angle/180);
>
> function onMouseDown(event) {
>     element.rotate(angle); //add rotation by step = angle
>
>     //the calulations
>     var temp = dy*cos1+dx*sin1;
>
>     dx = dx*cos1-dy*sin1;
>     dy = temp;
>
>     //Move the center point of the element.
>     element.position.x = x+dx; //this moves element center to x+dx pixels
>     element.position.y = y+dy; //this moves element center to y+dy pixels
> }
> ```

First, you kept incrementing the angle of rotation.  That would cause a bigger and bigger rotation with each mouse click.

Second, the element.rotate() function expects an angle in degrees, while Math.sin() and Math.cos() expect an angle in radians.

Third, I changed the shape from a circle to a rectangle so the effect of element.rotate() would be evident.

Finally, while I specified the corner of the rectangle at 100,100 the element.rotate() function rotates the rectangle around the center of the rectangle not the corner.  So you may have to take that into consideration in your finished product. Notice how the calculation of dx,dy subtracts x,y from element.position.x,element.positon.y and not from 100,100. I assume you will not be rotating a circle because if you are you don't need element.rotate().

Okay, here's how it works.  The dx,dy pair is the location of the center of the element to rotate relative to your pivot point.  Hence it's initial value is the difference of the element center point and the pivot point.

I only calculate the sine and cosine once.  Every mouse click rotates things by 1 degree.  After that to get a new value for dx,dy I use the trigonometric angle addition formulas for the sine and cosine.  That gives me a new position for the center of the element relative to the pivot point.  Add the pivot point to dx,dy and make that the x,y for the element and that's it!

Comment: We've been digging into the solution with a friend and it looks exactly like your solution. I am pleased to say that it works - like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
setRotationAngle(element, angle, x, y):
    setRotationAngle(element, angle)
    step_x = cos(angle) * (element.x - x) - sin(angle) * (element.y - y)
    step_y = sin(angle) * (element.x - x) + cos(angle) * (element.y - y)
    moveElement(element, step_x, step_y)
```

Comment: is the angle assumed to be in radians here?

Comment: What does it matter? Just be consistent, if you are working with radians make sure that the trigonometric functions get radian argument

Comment: http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/jVPRasIwFP2VS1/U6axu7EXxyb0Kgz2uY8T2aoMxKc2tNoj/vpu2mZPhtkIC9+bcc04O6SnSYo/RLHrdIaV5NIpSk/k6oYMoARXuURMsQOMRXgTl46UsU4X9h8lkNOUFvA3mEMcZbqTGDIQOU4kG/rpivJFKLY0yJZP11kqku968RbS7lxN6q5DPp55QaklSqLZ5wdR8/jTxgEIeDEFhJBusLwDHgMcfABe0NpVOSRoNRq9MZfHZHHUfD2xxAKdEJxQMl4YEYb+Rb24osgyapp9eO7CEBWt1/hLyqymGw3mo45hyhFSoSjVz1je9Sz/84e+y8qGmxnZCcAf94KAwVvqhcQ33UA94a8BW6t/AjnFucMmjUXJB6Y/hTmn4L1tBqdVqAyIDWEtLUm8hAMFnUKKtFNnrR/FNd7joMvFRUy4t7M0B7dcTZOIaBFOH6Dm9QtaoblE6pmzvfpvRXTFyGRjP/CesSxS75vXYaPb2fv4E

Comment: Just click anywhere on the white canvas on the example link. Am I missing something obvious?